# (Errno 101) Network is unreachable when executing python script using crontab

Tags: python, networking, cron

I want to retrieve some information form webstie using below script. It works well using command line. However, "error 101" problem is met when scheduled using crontab. I can' figure out the root cause, could you help to give some advice? Thanks!

```
    req = urllib2.Request(tempURL)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', ua)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=10)
        data = response.read()
        print data
        response.close()
        logging.info("Successfully get information about city " + str(k))
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        logging.info("Failed to crawl url " + tempURL)
```

My python environement:

The machine is redhat with python 2.6.6 installed.In order to use python2.7.4. I downloaded python-2.7.4.tar from web and build myself. Also add below environment variable to /etc/profile

```
PYHOME=$The unpacked path
```

After doing that, I got below information

```
[]$ python --version
 >>> Python 2.7.4
```

Then as googled, I create a shell script to set the ENV for python script.This shell script will be used for crontab schedule

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYHOME=$Python274_location
python my.py
```

If you execute 'python my.py 'in command line directly, you can get the correct result.But if scheduled in crontab, I will always get below errors.

```
ERROR:root:Failed to reach server. Reason: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

In my opinion, it should be related my python ENV, but has no clue till now.

Comment: How does cron entry look like for you? Do you export  correct PYTHONPATH? Do you launch script as the same user in cron as without cron?

Comment: it look like * * * * * /path/my.sh, I dont export PYTHONPATH, I export PYHome. yes, its same user

Comment: why PYHOME and not PYTHONHOME? It's in the official python documentation.